# Stategy pattern for game

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Hi I should use strategy pattern to write code of this game. I create Country class and Character Interface. But i'm little confused i don't know where should i add abilities?

player first has to select a country for his country, which could   be: Latveria, Ecotopia,Dinotopia. After  selecting the country, player has to assign a class for his/her character by selecting one of the following: King,Queen,Troll and Knight. Depending on its class a character   can have    different abilities: a  Knight  can handle any
kind of weapon  easily, which includesBow and Arrow, Swords, Knifes and Axes. King doesn't use any weapon, he can make strategy. Queen uses speacial Magic. Troll uses Knifes and Axes.  All types of characters can fight using its specific abilities. Besides, all can ride horse and swim.

Comment: some kind of UML package would be good for designing this sort of thing

Comment: I've created one. Since I can't upload here I uploaded it on imgur: http://imgur.com/KR7GDlx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the diagram you gave I would do this differently. Firstly you don't need a Country class instead just have it as a list and have your Character class have a Country Property which gets is value from this list depending on what the user picked.

Create a character class which contains all methods and properties which are the same for any character.

Now create the four different character types as classes containing all the attributes relative to that type, these four classes  will inherit from the Character class.

When the user creates a new character you create a new CharacterType instance and pass through the constructor the country and class type and then proceed to create the Character type as per data given then continue to set the character up as you need.

Something like this should work ok

Comment: instead of character interface I should create abilities interface. Did i get it right?

Comment: no the abilities i would put in the separate character types classes like queen and king etc. the abilities will be the attributes for each character type. So on your diagram you are pretty much right with the Character class, then just put the abilities as properties of the individual types. Hope this helps

Comment: I got it but shouldn't i use interface in strategy pattern? because in all examples there is interface.

Comment: you haven't specified the language you are using so is up to you how you implement with classes and interfaces, the core structure will be very similar what ever language you use just transfer the logic to suit you

Comment: ok :) I'll use java. I have last question is it a right structure for strategy pattern and is this logic right? http://imgur.com/qBgjQ0q

Comment: yes that looks better in terms of the structure as long as you link the abilities correctly